Existence of Non empty Subset of the Set {${1,2,...,9}$}
$A,B$ be subsets of $S=${$ 0,1,...,9$}, $ a\in A $ and $b \in B$ choosen randomly and $a+b$ takes each value  $0,1,...,9$ with equal probalibility. Then it implies that one of $A$ or $ B$ is singleton.(It's a 'True or False' Question)
What I tried to find if there is any pair of set $A$ and $B$ which are not singleton.
As each of sum value $0$ to $9$ has equal probabilty. only to find zero is $0+0$ so $0$ appears in both $A$ and $B$. And for this reason we will get a unique choice of $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $a+b=n$ for each $n \in S$.
In  this way I am trying to find a pair of $A$ and $B$ which are not singleton. But i this will take so much time to check whether such pair exists. So can any one give any suggestion or hint!
I added the Actual Statement from the source:
"Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of {$0, . . . , 9$}. It is given that, on choosing elements $a\in  A$ and $b \in B$ at random, $a + b$ takes each of the values $0, . . . , 9$ with equal probability. Then
one of $A$ or $B$ is singleton"

Are you assuming that both $A,B$ are non-empty?  You didn't state that as an assumption,  though you vaguely suggest it in the header.  And did you mean to restrict $a+b$ to ${0,\cdots, 9}$?  After all, in principle the sum could be as big as $18$.

For example, the sets $A={6,7}$, $B={7,8}$ pass your tests.  $a+b$ can not take any of the values in ${0, \cdots, 9}$ so it takes all of them with the same probability, namely $0$.  Note that you didn't say anything about the probability that $a+b\in {10, \cdots, 18}$.

Please edit to state all your assumptions clearly.  Perhaps it would help to link to the source of the problem, so we could see the original wording.  Failing that, please reproduce it without changing any of the words.

@lulu Now you can see edited version

As mentioned, the statement as written has "degenerate" counterexamples. If $A=\emptyset$, say, then you can't choose $a,b$ as requested so each probability is $0$, which is the same for all the values.  But I think my proposed counterexample (below) holds even if the problem statement were cleaned up.

Yeah should've been mention $A$ and $B$ nonempty but they didn't.

And they should mention that no sum greater than $9$ is possible.

@lulu Yes but that will work? (Statement is false)

Will what work?  As I mentioned, $A={6,7}$, $B={8,9}$ is a counterexample to the statement as written.  You can't get a sum in ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$ so all those probabilities are equally $0$.   I seriously doubt this is what they intended, but nothing in the problem statement excludes it.

Maybe they missed that part! Anyway your this counter example answers the question.

As mentioned in the comments, the assumptions are very vague and unclear.
That said, I think that $$A=\{0,1\}\quad \&\quad  B=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$$ is a counterexample, regardless of the details.  (Taking $a=0$ gives you all the even numbers exactly once and taking $a=1$ gives you all the odd numbers exactly once).
Should add:  I expect the problem intended to ask "Given two non-empty subsets $A,B$ of $\{0, \cdots, 9\}$ such that
I: the sum $a+b$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ is always between $0$ and $9$ (inclusive) and
II: if $a,b$ are chosen uniformly at random and independently of each other then the values in $\{0, \cdots, 9\}$ are all hit with equal probability
then is it true that one of $A,B$ must be a singleton?"   Certainly, my counterexample applies to that interpretation.

Yes! this counter examples works

Under the assumption that the random process of choosing a and b independently at random from A and B respectively gives a 1/10 chance of hitting each element of S, that is, sums of more than 9 are impossible, the only other solution (up to permuting A and B) is A={0,5}, B={0,1,2,3,4}.
